# Finding sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A\in B$, $B \in C$, but $A \notin C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am reading a book on mathematical proofs by Albert D. Polimeni, Ping Zhang, Gary Chartrand. I came across a practice problem that states

> Give examples of 3-sets: $A$, $B$ and $C$; such that $A\in B$, $B \in C$ but $A \notin C$.

How can I find such sets? The problem tells us $B = \{A,b_1,b_2,\ldots\}$ and $C = \{B,c_1,c_2\}$. To me it looks as if $A \in B$, $B \in C$  then it is always the case that $A \in C$. How can I go about understanding this problem?

Comment: see for instance $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$, $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\emptyset\notin\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take
$$A=\color{red}\{1\color{red}\}\\
B=\color{blue}\{1,\color{red}\{1\color{red}\}\color{blue}\}\\
C=\{1,\color{blue}\{1,\{1\}\color{blue}\}\}$$

Note that $A\in B$ and $B\in C$ although $A\notin C$ (as none of the elements of $C$ are $A$).

Comment: so A does not belong to C, even if C = {1, {1 , A } } }? I think I am missing something key about the definitions for a set and its elements.

Comment: @RSM  $C$ has two elements: $1$ and $\{1,A\}$. Neither of these elements is equal to $A$. So $A\notin C$.

Comment: @RSM this may seem a little confusing at first, you should properly check the definition of an element of a set. However, I placed an edit- see if that helps.

Comment: @SayanDutta it did help, thank you Sayan !

Answer (score 4):

Your are likely conflating the given exercise with:

- "Find sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A\subseteq B$, $B \subseteq C$, but $A \not\subseteq C$."

A simpler example than in the other answer is:
$$A=\{1\}\\B=\{\{1\}\}\\C=\{\{\{1\}\}\}.$$

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that a simpler way to express this is:

$$A = \text{(whatever you like)}\\
B = \{A\} \\
C =\{B\}
$$

And we are done.  Certainly we have $A\in B$ and $B\in C$.

Since $B$ is the only element of $C$, we have $A\notin C$ unless $A=B$.  But $A=B = \{A\}$ is impossible because of the foundation axiom.  (Or if you don't believe the foundation axiom, simply take any $A$ you want with $A\ne \{A\}$. Every set you have ever seen is an example.)

Taking $A=\emptyset$ gets us Sassatelli Giulio's example from the comment.  Taking $A=\{1\}$ gets us ryang's answer.  But really $A$ can be literally anything at all.